# what is the qps of Redis and mysql

Tags: mysql, redis

in some basic server, is there a benchmark compare between mysql and Redis?
some report said the Redis' QPS is about 100k/s ,and the mysql web site say it benchmark is 0.8M/s , it can't be the truth that mysql is faster than Redis because the server is not equal, so in the same server condition, what is the basic benchmark QPS of mysql and Redis? can anybody show some benchmark report?

Answer (score 2):

Redis is in-memory and is faster. Some of the RDBMS overheads of MySQL don't need to be in Redis. If you were to try benchmarking the two, you'll see that Redis' QPS (queries per second) will be higher than MySQL.

In your question, you describe throughput, not QPS.

Here's a nice benchmark between the two: https://blog.boardiesitsolutions.com/mysql-database-vs-redis/

Here's Redis' benchmark: https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks. That gives you a decent amount of information about speed of Redis, but not in comparison with other RDBMS.

DZone has a blog about MySQL vs. MySQL and Redis. That shows you performance improvement with Redis in the mix: https://dzone.com/articles/redis-vs-mysql-benchmarks (same as https://fullstackgeek.blogspot.com/2019/04/redis-vs-mysql-benchmark.html)

When choosing database servers, do think about various scenarios besides speed such as disaster recovery, backup/restore, master/slave configuration, transactions, data loss prevention, transaction complexity, data types, etc.

Comment: the link you mentioned I have saw before, thanks anyway ! maybe I have to benchmark redis and mysql in save machine, and can get the difference of them，so i will to buy a vps for experiment!

Comment: You can just install virtualbox, set up a guest Linux machine and put both redis and MySQL on it and run your tests. You don’t need a VPS.